# Match (highlight) invalid Hungarian notation variables syntax

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

We follow our own defined coding standard ([Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)) as per our checklist, using Notepad++:

1. *Check that all variables are valid according to Hungarian notation identifier naming convention, and match & highlight invalid Hungarian notation variables syntax:*

   `String` variables should start with `s` as follows:

   ```
   String sTest = null;
   ```

   For `int` it should be `i`:

   ```
   int iCount = 0;
   ```

   If there is a variable `String Test = null;` or a variable `int Count = 0;` I want to highlight them as they don't start with `s` and `i`.

Comment: In the future, please don't cross-post your questions. Ask them on one site, and if they're off topic they will be migrated anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for a Regular Expression to match (and highlight) all the cases you describe.

- This Regex will match any `String` variable initialization that
  doesn't have the character `s` in the beginning of its name: `String [^s].*?;`
- This Regex will match any `int` variable initialization that
  doesn't have the character `i` in the beginning of its name: `int [^i].*?;`
- This Regex combines both of them: `String [^s].*?;|int [^i].*?;`

  [(RegExr Test)](http://regexr.com?325mg)